# How to get users first and last name?

Tags: google-app-maker

@user.email seems to instantly print email address of a user that is using the app on any widget.
Is there a way to get User Name (First Last) in a similar way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I usually use involves using the directory model. Follow these steps:

1.) Enable the directory model by creating it, I usually name it **directory**

[image]

2.) Next, go to the **DATASOURCES** section of the directoy model you just created and click on the **ADD DATASOURCE** button. I usually name this datasource **activeUser**.

[image]

3.) Add the following to any server script:

```
function getActiveUser() {    
  var dirQuery = app.models.directory.newQuery();
  dirQuery.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals =  Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var userResult = dirQuery.run();
  return userResult;     
}
```

4.) Go back to the **activeUser** datasource. Add the following to the **Server Script Query**:

```
return getActiveUser();
```

And change the query page size to **1**.

[image]

5.) Now all you have to make sure is that the widget where you will print the user name has the datasource **activeUser** either directly or inherited. Then you simply bind it to the **FullName** property.

[image]